# xlwings use global variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, xlwings

I am working on an interactive excel sheet using xlwings. When a button is clicked, a matplotlib plot will be shown in the active sheet. The data is from a large csv file.

The current solution works but there is one catch: every time it plots, the external file has to be read. So it is really slow. I am thinking to use a global variable to buffer the data but don't know how to do it.

Below is a sketch of the program.

python program:

```
@xw.func
def plot_fig():
    wb = xw.Wookbook.caller()
    df = pandas.read_excel("large_data_file.xlsx")
    pylab.plot(df["time"],df["data"])
    xw.Plot(pl.gcf()).show("data")
```

Comment: Try to set the `OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION` to True in your VBA settings. This prevents the interpreter from shutting down after every call.

Comment: I have the same problem. Setting OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION=True did not help me. I use xlwings-0.10.0